# C++11 for loop over partially populated array without boilerplate index?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I'm looking for a marginally cleaner way of iterating through a slice of a partially-populated array. I don't think that `std::valarray<>/std::slice` will work, and even if I felt like waiting until 2017 or so, it's not clear to me that `std::dynarray<>` would fit either.

```
int main() {
  // Some C-style API fills n <= vals.size() array slots.
  std::array<uint32_t, 1024> vals;
  size_t n = get(src, vals.data(), vals.size());

  // Looking for something like this, though anything better appreciated.
  for (auto &v : slice(vals, n)) {
    whatever(v);
  }

  // Unsatisfactory: i only grabs &v, which is obscured from the loop header.
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    auto &v = vals[i];
    whatever(v);
  }
}

// I might make these utility templates if need be ...
template <typename T, unsigned int NStride = 1>
struct Slice {
  Slice(T *, size_t end, size_t begin = 0);

  template <unsigned int N>
  Slice(std::array<T, N> &a, size_t end, size_t begin = 0);

  using iterator = T *;
  iterator begin();
  iterator end();
  // const_iterators, bazillion operators, etc. ...
};

template <typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int NStride = 1>
Slice<T> slice(std::array<T, N> &a, size_t end, size_t begin = 0);
```

Do any of the STL, boost, etc. implement something similar to my approach or better?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Is this compatible with the range-based for? A cursory glance makes it look like it uses `std::for_each` or some boost variant, which I consider a bit ugly syntactically.

Comment: It's got an adapter called "iterator_range" which is perfectly compatible. However, the whole idea of Boost::range is to avoid iteration over ranges in favor of range algorithms.

Comment: OK, I see what they're doing a bit better now. Unfortunately, I'm not really looking to add more indirection (just the opposite actually). I want to make processing C API array slices cleaner and more idiot-proof, for which the range-based for seems like a pretty good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda with a `std::for_each` algorithm removes the index, although it still has a bit of boilerplate:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.begin() + 3, [](int &n){
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

http://ideone.com/toaiUG

`std::array` has a random access iterator so you can add your `n` to it as the end of the range.